# Air StageWebView html5 content vs native browser performance

Tags: html, performance, mobile, air, stagewebview

I am using StageWebView for displaying the html5 contents (a simple game) in AIR mobile app. 
On some devices, Nexus 4 for ex., html5 in StageWebView has 10 FPS istead of 50-60 in mobile Google Chrome on same device! But StageWebView uses same Chrome version on device...

How its possible? How improve performance in StageWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stagewebview, their is an option to use Native webkit or System webkit. Here the webkit is the engine to render the html content or anything inside the viewport.

For Eg:
    Am going to open one index.html in StageWebView using Native Webkit, it takes adobe's webkit to render the html. If am using System webkit that page will render by using systems browser engine like internet explore / Safari etc.. based on the OS.

But, in mobile stagewebview always pick the system webkit. For better under standing, open www.html3test.com website by these methods while initializing StageWebView.

**StageWebView( true ) - For native browser support 

  StageWebView( false ) - For Embedded browser support.**

**Native browser engine is always faster than Embedded browser.**